# How do I make my mesh at joints bend smoothly?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, vertex-weights, remesh

I am trying to rig a model here. I have a ripped model from a game here that I've downloaded from the Internet. All the bones deform the mesh smoothly. Here is an example of the shoulder joint here:
[image]

I decided to edit the model's clothes. I have assigned the extra meshes onto the model as vertex groups. However, When I move the same bones again, this happens:

[image]

The weird thing that when I reviewed the original model's weights, it was all zero (blue all over). This made me confused. Now I have edited the mesh, how do I achieve the same quality as the original model?

Please note that the arm/shoulder mesh is still the same just I recolored it, added extra meshes on top (like armor) and reassigned it to the bones. Also that my edited model also has no weights.Corrective smooth modifier and smooth modifier also does not work for me.

Please is there a way to do this without going through all the weight painting? I need help as soon as possible.

Comment: depending on how you've edited the cloth, the vertices may have inherited some weights got. Blue doesn't mean your vertex is not assigned, it may be 0.1 or 0.01, enable the Zero Weight option (in Viewport Overlays, when in Weight Paint mode), or check each vertex weight in the N panel > Item > Vertex Weights to make sur that they are not part of any vertex group. They are probably part of a group so you need to make some correction, you can paint them or the right of the Vertex Groups list, dropdown menu > Remove from All Groups then reassign correctly, either manually or with Assign

Comment: @moonboots I tried reassigning but ended up the same. I found out if I assign the arm of the original model again it will be the same as my edited model. Does this info help you? When I enabled Zero Weight option, it was all black. I even used the dropper and detected all the meshes but it was all zero. What do I do?

Comment: maybe share your file if this is possible? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots maybe it is possible to copy weights from a model to another? Please answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238773/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-armature-weights-from-one-model-to-another

Answer (score 1):

I edited the weights for the shoulder and arm bones so it matches the original model as closed as possible. Then, fixed.